# SelectSingleNode based on value of tag

Tags: xpath, xmldocument, selectsinglenode

This code works:

```
XmlNode Key = Site.SelectSingleNode(PathString, manager);
```

But what I really want is essentially:

```
string desiredValue="Ribeye";
XmlNode Key = Site.SelectSingleNode(PathString[Value=desiredValue], manager);
```

desiredValue is NOT an attribute, and the string variable will be changing between uses. So if my tag was FavoriteSteak, the XML line would be:

```
<FavoriteSteak>Ribeye</FavoriteSteak>
```

...and I want the SelectSingleNode call to return an instance of FavoriteSteak that equaled "Ribeye".

How do I write the filter?

Comment: Try `FavoriteSteak[text()=desiredValue]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andersson for the inspiration. The resulting code looks like:

```
                var FilterString = String.Format("[text()='{0}']", desiredValue);

            XmlNode Key = Site.SelectSingleNode(KeyPath+FilterString, manager);
```